# Storing value of a variable as a type

Tags: powershell, powercli

Alright - really nitpicky, but i HATE writing the same code twice (even if at this point it would have saved me more time)

So I'm writing a PowerCLI function that has 2 switch parameters to either find a poweredon or poweredoff event.

behold

```
function pGet-PowerEvent {

[cmdletbinding()]

PARAM (

[parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,
Mandatory=$true,
Position=0)]
[string[]]
$Entity,

[parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,
Mandatory=$false,
Position=1)]
[switch]
$onEvent,

[parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,
Mandatory=$false,
Position=2)]
[Switch]
$offEvent

)

if ($onEvent) {
$EventType = "VmPoweredOnEvent"
}

if ($offEvent) {
$EventType = "VmPoweredOffEvent"
}

$entity.ForEach{write-host $_; Get-VIEvent -Entity $_ -MaxSamples([int]::MaxValue) | ?{$_ -is [vmware.vim."$EventType"] | 
select createdtime, username }

}
```

and running the command:

```
pGet-PowerEvent -Entity $vm -OnEvent
```

and the error:

```
Cannot convert the "[VMware.Vim.VmPoweredOffEvent]" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Type".
```

However when i run this command - it sees [vmware.vim.vmpoweredoffevent] as a string, rather than a type.

But i need the variable to be the type. And the value of the variable as the type.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question and include the command being used to invoke the `pGet-PowerEvent` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want either:

```
Where-Object { $_.GetType().FullName -eq "vmware.vim.$EventType" }
```

Or:

```
Where-Object { $_ -is ([type]"vmware.vim.$EventType") }
```

Or this may work better for you:

```
Where-Object { $_.GetType().Name -eq $EventType }
```

---

As an aside, you almost certainly don't want all three of your parameters to have `ValueFromPipeline=$true`.

If you run this:

```
Get-VM $VMName | pGet-PowerEvent
```

It's basically identical to running this:

```
$VM = Get-VM @VMParameters
pGet-PowerEvent -Entity $VM -onEvent:$VM -offEvent:$VM
```

You see how that doesn't make sense?

Additionally, it doesn't really make sense to assign `Position` or `Mandatory=$false` to switch parameters.  There is no reason you'd ever want to do this:

```
pGet-PowerEvent $VI $true $false
```

Instead of this:

```
pGet-PowerEvent $VI -onEvent
```

It's just much more readable.  If you need to call it dynamically, you would want to do something like this:

```
$OnEventSetting = (Get-Date).DayOfWeek -eq [DayOfWeek]::Monday
$OffEventSetting = (Get-Date).DayOfWeek -eq [DayOfWeek]::Tuesday
pGet-PowerEvent $VI -onEvent:$OnEventSetting -offEvent:$OffEventSetting
```

Comment: cool. So it's not about creating a variable with a value as a type (which doesn't make much sense anyway) - but just forcing it when you invoke the string to be a type. Makes sense. And as far as the parameter settings, lol... it's just a habit. Old habits die hard i guess. Thanks for the info though